# Button when clicked application got Crash in android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have fragment class that use button, the button have to login the user if exist or have to show text user not valid. I have use sqlite database. But the problem is when i click on the login button my application got crash.
Here is the attach code of Frag

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
String userName;
EditText testUser;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstfragment,container,false);

    // create a instance of SQLite Database
    loginDataBaseAdapter = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(getActivity());
    loginDataBaseAdapter = loginDataBaseAdapter.open();


    //get the reference of the design


   final  testUser = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameToLogin);
    final EditText testPassword = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordToLogin);
    final Button btnLogin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);
    final Button btnCreate=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateAccount);

    //set OnClick Listener on login button

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

             userName=testUser.getText().toString();

              EditText testPassword = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordToLogin);
              String password = testPassword.getText().toString();


            //fetch the password from the database for respective user name

            String storedPassword = loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(userName);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),storedPassword,1).show();

            // check if the Stored password matches with  Password entered by user
            if (password.equals(storedPassword)) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Congrats:Login Sucessfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           } else {
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }




        }
    });
return view;
}
```

My Db class "LoginDataBaseAdapter" i have one function that check the password from where we have passed the username. Here is the code

```
 public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName) {
    Cursor cursor = db.query("LOGIN", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() < 1) // UserName Not Exist
    {
        cursor.close();
        return "NOT EXIST";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
    cursor.close();
    return password;
}
```

Now i cant figure it out that where i am missing. When i click the login button my application gets crash. 
Thank you in advance.

my logcat:

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.betatestregister.LoginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(LoginDataBaseAdapter.java:68)
        at com.example.betatestregister.FirstFragment$1.onClick(FirstFragment.java:52)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My LoginDataBaseAdapter class code:

```
package com.example.betatestregister;
```

/**
 * Created by Rohan on 24/05/13.
 */

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import android.widget.Toast;




public class LoginDataBaseAdapter {
static final String DATABASE_NAME = "login.db";
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
// TODO: Create public field for each column in your table.
// SQL Statement to create a new database.
static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + "LOGIN" +
        "( " + "ID" + " integer primary key autoincrement," + "USERNAME  text,PASSWORD 
text); ";
// Variable to hold the database instance
public SQLiteDatabase db;
// Context of the application using the database.
private final Context context;
// Database open/upgrade helper
private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;

public LoginDataBaseAdapter(Context _context) {
    context = _context;
    dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public LoginDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException {

//        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    db.close();
}

public SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance() {
    return db;
}

public void insertEntry(String userName, String password) {
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    // Assign values for each row.
    newValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
    newValues.put("PASSWORD", password);

    // Insert the row into your table
    db.insert("LOGIN", null, newValues);
    ///Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public int deleteEntry(String UserName) {
    //String id=String.valueOf(ID);
    String where = "USERNAME=?";
    int numberOFEntriesDeleted = db.delete("LOGIN", where, new String[]{UserName});
    // Toast.makeText(context, "Number fo Entry Deleted Successfully : 
"+numberOFEntriesDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return numberOFEntriesDeleted;
}

public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName) {
    Cursor cursor = db.query("LOGIN", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{userName}, 
null, null, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() < 1) // UserName Not Exist
    {
        cursor.close();
      //  Toast.makeText(context, "Number fo Entry Deleted Successfully : 
"+numberOFEntriesDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return "NOT EXIST";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
    cursor.close();
    return password;
}

public void updateEntry(String userName, String password) {
    // Define the updated row content.
    ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
    // Assign values for each row.
    updatedValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
    updatedValues.put("PASSWORD", password);

    String where = "USERNAME = ?";
    db.update("LOGIN", updatedValues, where, new String[]{userName});
}

}
```

Comment: Please post your error log

Comment: @Rohan Ale post ur logcat output with line number..and show the line number where it thorws exception.

Comment: Please post your logcat...your db is null, it seems

Comment: why do you call loginDataBaseAdapter = loginDataBaseAdapter.open();? call loginDataBaseAdapter.open(); should be enough.

Comment: @Pragnani if the db is null then it should show the message Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: @RohanAle No it won't show..Because app will crash because of `NullPointerException`. Also your logcat is not relative..Please post red lines in your logcat

Comment: show full code for LoginDataBaseAdapter.java

Comment: `NullPointerException` at `getSinlgeEntry(LoginDataBaseAdapter.java:68)`,

As I said in the comment. your `db` is `null`.

Comment: @Pragnani how can we handle the NullPointerException

Comment: @RohanAle Post your `LoginDataBaseAdapter` code

Comment: @Pragnani in  the code..   testUser=(EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameToLogin);
when i mouse hover on it, it shows it may produce java.nullpointerexceptio....help me out

Comment: @RohanAle Sorry for the late reply... Try to set ` testUse` as field and then refer them in the `onCreateView()`, use `testUse.getText()` instead

Comment: @Pragnani still not working .....
 i am doing like this 
testUser=(EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameToLogin);
                 userName=testUser.getText().toString();

Answer (score 1):

```
loginDataBaseAdapter = loginDataBaseAdapter.open();
```

remove above code.
Use only

```
loginDataBaseAdapter.open();
```

You are modifing your loginDataBaseAdapter after creating an instance of it.

Comment: I am Getting still the error .....

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.betatestregister.LoginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(LoginDataBaseAdapter.java:68)
        at com.example.betatestregister.FirstFragment$1.onClick(FirstFragment.java:52)

Answer (score 1):

```
public LoginDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException {

//        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

uncomment this line

```
//        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

This method does nothing now, but is supposed to get a writeable instance of database.
It didn't do it so db is null and You get NPE.

Answer (score 1):

In Your case You get some cursor back that is null. First You have to check why it is null. But to prevent crash the app when cursor is null, You can possibly do somthing like this:

```
    String storedPassword="";
    String checkPassowrd = loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(userName);

    if(checkPassword!=null){

     storedPassword = checkPassword;

    }
```

and I recommend You to set Your getSingleEntry method like this:

```
    public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName) {
     Cursor cursor = db.query("LOGIN", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
     if (cursor.getCount() < 1) // UserName Not Exist
          {
            cursor.close();
              return "NOT EXIST";
        }else{
       cursor.moveToFirst();
      String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
       cursor.close();
       return password;
      }
   }
```

What is irritating me, do You really want  to let Your cursor on the first entry? There is no cursor.MoveToNext() ?